# ImageMagick create PDF version 1.4 from image?

Tags: image-processing, pdf-generation, imagemagick

I know that I can use ImageMagick's convert tool to turn different image files into PDF documents.  However, is there some way to specify what version of PDF document I want to use for the output?  Can I convert an image to a PDF v1.4 document?

I am trying to find a way to automate the conversion of image files (probably SVG) to PDF files that need to be sent to a printing service.  The printer's service requires the PDF files to meet certain requirements, and one of them is that the PDF file is v1.4.  My version of convert is "6.5.7-8 2010-12-02 Q16".

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question on superuser.com

https://superuser.com/questions/193791/batch-convert-pdf-versions

will give you some hints how to change the version number in the PDF afterwards.